# How to get Image src using Swift-Html-Parser

Tags: swift

I am a newbie on Swift and Swift-HTML-Parser. I am using Swift-HTML-Parser from : https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Swift-HTML-Parser

I need some help for below question.

```
    let myURLString = "http://MytestingWebsite.com/MyAds.html"
    let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString)

    var error: NSError?

    let myHTMLString = NSString(contentsOfURL: myURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

    if let error = error {

        //for below question 2
        println("Error : \(error)")

    } else {

        // code

    }

1) How to get the Src of the Image if there is a) only one image b) a collection of images?  

      < image Src="....."/>

2) What to use to show message when there is an error?


Adding the the required files as per the above link for Swift-HTML-Parser :

1. Add a Bridging file. click Project and goto Building Setting 
Use search: type in Bridging 
Double click on the result : Objective-C Bridging Header 
and Click (+) at the Top to add.

Error msg show: When adding file name with (-) Like Swift-HTML-Parser-Bridging-Header.h 

So, I add SwiftHTMLParserBridgingHeader

2) Copy the File Swift-HTML-Parser-Bridging-Header.h and rename it as SwiftHTMLParserBridgingHeader.h in the project file.

3) Copy HTMLParser.Swift and HTMLNode.swift

4) Have added the reference Libxml2.dylib

When compile, (2) and (3) have red dot. Am I doing something wrong?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This have have a emum for each node that you can search in the HTML

```
public enum HTMLNodeType : String {
    case HTMLUnkownNode     = ""
    case HTMLHrefNode       = "href"
    case HTMLTextNode       = "text"
    case HTMLCodeNode       = "code"
    case HTMLSpanNode       = "span"
    case HTMLPNode          = "p"
    case HTMLLiNode         = "li"
    case HTMLUiNode         = "ui"
    case HTMLImageNode      = "image"
    case HTMLOlNode         = "ol"
    case HTMLStrongNode     = "strong"
    case HTMLPreNode        = "pre"
    case HTMLBlockQuoteNode = "blockquote"
}
```

From the example they have in the website:

```
var err : NSError?
//myHTMLString is the value you retrive from the website
var parser     = HTMLParser(html: myHTMLString, error: &err)
if err != nil {
    //This will log the error and exit the app
    //You probably should display an alert to the user
    println(err)
    exit(1)
}

var bodyNode   = parser.body

if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.findChildTags(HTMLNodeType.HTMLImageNode) {
    for node in inputNodes {
        println(node.contents)
        //this should display the address where the Image is
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not test it as I had problem to install the Swift-HTML-Parser-Header.h as required. 1) In Project, goto Build Settings, use search to get Objective-C Bridging header. Then Double click the result and click (+) to add . Got error msg: Swift-HTML-Parser-Header.h isnt a valid name for build setting... 2) Copy the HTMLParser & Node, but they all have red dot sign. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I don't think you need a bridge files as the library is in swift 1.2 already

Comment: It seems that this is a wrap around libxml2 so you need to install that too

Comment: See my update for how I added the bridging header file. These HTMLParser and HTMLNode.Swift have red dot even I delete the Bridging header file.   It wont compile. Do you have this problem? I am using Xcode6.3 the latest.

Comment: It work for well form HTML. In my case, I have no control over the Not-well form HTML source. So, this is not working. Thanks

Comment: That is a shame, but you have the source code so you can add new HTMLNoseTypes in the code and make it work. Sorry I never use this tool before I just research to help you. Good lucky